# Call <link rel=“stylesheet” href=“”> On A Specific Part Of My Page Without Overriding My Current CSS Style

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, jquery-file-upload

I am trying to call `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">` in the header.php that is linked to my post_form page for the jQuery file uploader that is on the post_form without it overriding the css for the rest of the page. I have tried removing the left table cell, attempted to float the file uploader left, and tried to extend the width of the file uploader to 100% to no avail.

the code update is

```html
<tr>
      <th>Upload:</th>
      <td width="250">        <!-- The global progress state -->
        <div class="fileupload-progress fade" style="display:none">
         <!-- The global progress bar -->
         <div class="progress" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
         <!-- The extended global progress state -->
         <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
       </div>      
      <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
      </div>     
      <table role="presentation"><tbody class="files"><textarea cols="60"></textarea></tbody></table>           
      </form> 
      
      <!-- The blueimp Gallery widget -->
      <div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-controls" data-filter=":even">
       <div class="slides"></div>
        <h3 class="title"></h3>
        <a class="prev">‹</a>
        <a class="next">›</a>
        <a class="close">×</a>
        <a class="play-pause"></a>
        <ol class="indicator"></ol>
      </div>
      </td>
      <td>
      <form>
      <label for="theme-switcher">Theme:</label>
      <select id="theme-switcher" class="pull-right">
       <option value="black-tie">Black Tie</option>
       <option value="blitzer">Blitzer</option>
       <option value="cupertino">Cupertino</option>
       <option value="dark-hive" selected>Dark Hive</option>
       <option value="dot-luv">Dot Luv</option>
       <option value="eggplant">Eggplant</option>
       <option value="excite-bike">Excite Bike</option>
       <option value="flick">Flick</option>
       <option value="hot-sneaks">Hot sneaks</option>
       <option value="humanity">Humanity</option>
       <option value="le-frog">Le Frog</option>
       <option value="mint-choc">Mint Choc</option>
       <option value="overcast">Overcast</option>
       <option value="pepper-grinder">Pepper Grinder</option>
       <option value="redmond">Redmond</option>
       <option value="smoothness">Smoothness</option>
       <option value="south-street">South Street</option>
       <option value="start">Start</option>
       <option value="sunny">Sunny</option>
       <option value="swanky-purse">Swanky Purse</option>
       <option value="trontastic">Trontastic</option>
       <option value="ui-darkness">UI Darkness</option>
       <option value="ui-lightness">UI Lightness</option>
       <option value="vader">Vader</option>
      </select>
      </form><!-- The file upload form used as target for the file upload widget -->
<form id="fileupload" action="//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- Redirect browsers with JavaScript disabled to the origin page -->
    <noscript><input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/"></noscript>
    <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
    <div class="fileupload-buttonbar">
        <div class="fileupload-buttons">
            <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
            <span class="fileinput-button">
                <span>Add files...</span>
                <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
            </span>
            <button type="submit" class="start">Start upload</button>
            <button type="reset" class="cancel">Cancel upload</button>
            <button type="button" class="delete">Delete</button>
            <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
            <!-- The global file processing state -->
            <span class="fileupload-process"></span>
        </div>
        <!-- The global progress state -->
        <div class="fileupload-progress fade" style="display:none">
            <!-- The global progress bar -->
            <div class="progress" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
            <!-- The extended global progress state -->
            <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
    <table role="presentation"><tbody class="files"></tbody></table>
</form>
<br>
<!-- The blueimp Gallery widget -->
<div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-controls" data-filter=":even">
    <div class="slides"></div>
    <h3 class="title"></h3>
    <a class="prev">‹</a>
    <a class="next">›</a>
    <a class="close">×</a>
    <a class="play-pause"></a>
    <ol class="indicator"></ol>
</div>
<!-- The template to display files available for upload -->
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-upload fade">
        <td>
            <span class="preview"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="name">{%=file.name%}</p>
            <strong class="error"></strong>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="size">Processing...</p>
            <div class="progress"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            {% if (!i && !o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                <button class="start" disabled>Start</button>
            {% } %}
            {% if (!i) { %}
                <button class="cancel">Cancel</button>
            {% } %}
        </td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
<!-- The template to display files available for download -->
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">
        <td>
            <span class="preview">
                {% if (file.thumbnailUrl) { %}
                    <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery><img src="{%=file.thumbnailUrl%}"></a>
                {% } %}
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p class="name">
                <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" download="{%=file.name%}" {%=file.thumbnailUrl?'data-gallery':''%}>{%=file.name%}</a>
            </p>
            {% if (file.error) { %}
                <div><span class="error">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</div>
            {% } %}
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="size">{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class="delete" data-type="{%=file.deleteType%}" data-url="{%=file.deleteUrl%}"{% if (file.deleteWithCredentials) { %} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}'{% } %}>Delete</button>
            <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1" class="toggle">
        </td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
      </td>
     </tr>
```

[the fileuploader now shows with the css styles as it is supposed to, but it only appears when on the right side of my post_form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEzxI.png)

[this is how the fileuploader shows when i add audio or video files. it works when it is placed in the right cell of my post_form, but not on the left which is where I would like it to show.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILPN7.png)

Comment: Thanks for the edit A.P. and guradio I tried gurdaio's edit <div id="stylesheet" class"stylesheet"> around the code, but still applied the bootstrap css stylesheet on the whole post_form instead of just the Image field. Both <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="default" /> (layout for admin panel) and the <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"> for the file uploader in the header is referenced as "stylesheet" would that be an issue though the "screen.css" says "default" in its reference?

Comment: Update: I am able to get the css to show without overriding the css of my post_form, but now the file uploader buttons show on the right side of my post_form instead of the left. When I place it on the left side of the cell the css style disappears for some reason and the uploader no longer functions.

Answer (score 0):

The most spesific css selector will be the one choosen, if the selectors are equal the last selector will be chosen

so

```
body #divID{

}
```

will override

```
#divID{

}
```

The above selector is more sepsific than the last one. if they where the same, the last one would be choosen. I sugest you load you're css last, and override bootstrap in you're css file

Comment: Hi Nicholas thanks for the suggestion I tried reversing the order of where the two css files were located and it showed how it appears in the second screenshot from my comment.